# PHP call a method from other class that is not a child of

Tags: php

I have two classes A and B. 
So if B extends A then I can access A's method and it works fine as expected like so:

```
abstract class A{
    public function sum($num1, $num2){
        return $num1 + $num2;
    }
}

class B extends A{} 

$test = new B(); 

echo $test->sum(1,2); // output 3
```

But what if I don't want B to extend A and still want to access A's method in B. Is it possible?

I tried the code below by instantiating a new A inside B called `$c` but it doesn't work:

```
abstract class A{
    public function sum($num1, $num2){
        return $num1 + $num2;
    }
}

class B{
    $c = new A;
    public function get_sum($n1, $n2){
        return $c->sum($n1, $n2);
    }
} 

$test = new B; 

echo $test->get_sum(1,2);
```

Any idea if its all possible to call a class method that is not a parent of the caller?

Comment: What is the original task you're solving? Answer would pretty much vary on what you originally wanted to achieve.

Comment: instead of `return $c->` should be `return $this->c->`

Comment: @Cheery tried `return $this->c->sum($n1, $n2);` but it doesn't work either.

Comment: @reymangana what error message did you get? `c` should be initialized in constructor or other function - you can not use `new A` in the place you try to do it.

Comment: @zerkms say I have two classes Betting and Player. I find it awkward to say Player is a child class of Betting just so I can call Player1->bet which is a Betting's method.

Comment: Must the class A be abstract? [demo](https://eval.in/216121)

Comment: @Glavić I intentionally set A to abstract because I don't want to instantiate it. However, I will try to follow your other suggestion that is to create a constructor.

Comment: @Glavić your demo is perfect except that A needs to be abstract to avoid instantiation.

Comment: @reymangana: so if a "Betting" is not a player - why should it have its methods?

Comment: @zerkms because I believe the method `bet` should be put in the Betting class instead of in the Player class and that it would be called in the Player class only if needed.

Comment: @reymangana: or may be because `bet` belongs to neither of them and must be put into a dedicated class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two ways you might use the sum() method without having B extend A.  If A were not an abstract class, then you could instantiate an A object and assign it to a property of B, as follows:

```
<?php
class A{
    public function sum($num1, $num2){
        return $num1 + $num2;
    }
}

class B {
    public $property;

    public function __construct($object) {
        $this->property = $object;
    }
}
$obj = new A();
$test = new B($obj); 
echo $test->property->sum(1,2),"\n"; // output 3
?>
```

The preceding technique I believe goes by term "composition".  In this case, any sum work gets delegated to the property which has been assigned an object that can handle that task.

You could instead solve the problem by using a trait since your A class only has a method and no properties, as follows:

```
<?php
trait A {
    public function sum($num1, $num2){
        return $num1 + $num2;
    }
}

class B {

    use A;

}

$test = new B(); 
echo $test->sum(2,3); // output 5
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In that case you should declare the method you want to use as static. Check [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

I suggest you alter your code (add static to the function)

```
 abstract class A{
   public  function sum($num1, $num2){
    return $num1 + $num2;
 }
}
```

And for your B class

```
 class B{

public function get_sum($n1, $n2){
    return A::sum($n1, $n2);
   }
 }
```

Comment: @geoandi it works but my concern is that its a static function and I want to avoid static functions as much as possible because I will be using that method in other class that might need it.

Comment: It works also without sum() being a static function.

Answer (score 1):

Access it statically. Example:

```
abstract class A{
    public function sum($num1, $num2){
        return $num1 + $num2;
    }
}

class B{
    public function get_sum($n1, $n2){
        return A::sum($n1, $n2);
    }
}
$test = new B;
echo $test->get_sum(1,2);
```

Comment: it works but I don't want A to be instantiated from outside thats why I deliberately make it abstract. now your code breaks if I make A abstract.